# Tensorflow : TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting a tensor as an argument, Now I want to create some variables, I am trying `tf.get_variables` (I don't want to use `tf.Variable`):

```
input=tensor_argument
    
sequence_length = tf.shape(inputs)[1]  # the length 
    
hidden_size = tf.shape(inputs)[2] # hidden size 

W_omega = tf.get_variable(name='w_omega',shape=[sequence_length,sequence_length],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))
```

When I run this code, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'
```

I tried with `tf.shape` and `tf.size()` but nothing is working.
Example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


data=np.random.randint(0,10,[2,4,300])

tensor_va=tf.constant(data)

d=tf.shape(tensor_va)[1]
W_omega = tf.get_variable(name='a_omega', shape=[d,d], dtype=tf.float32,
                          initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01, 0.01))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(W_omega))
```

How to use or convert tensor to int for `get_variable`?

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution in TF 2.3, where eager execution enabled by default. To fix above issue, you should convert `d` from `tensor` to `numpy`.

Complete working code as shown below

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
print(tf.__version__)

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


data=np.random.randint(0,10,[2,4,300])

tensor_va=tf.constant(data)

d=tensor_va.numpy().shape [1]

W_omega = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(name='a_omega', shape=[d,d], dtype=tf.float32,
                          initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01, 0.01))

print(W_omega)
```

Output:

```
2.3.0
<tf.Variable 'a_omega:0' shape=(4, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.00958031, -0.00010247,  0.00161975, -0.00098458],
       [ 0.00287828, -0.00026206, -0.00369554,  0.00339144],
       [-0.00205746, -0.00392851,  0.00062867,  0.00173409],
       [-0.00409856,  0.0012137 , -0.00762768, -0.00545195]],
      dtype=float32)>
```